# Error is occured when auto remove in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 10: /etc/environment: bin: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic; try https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason for the error is as stated.  Go look at /etc/environment.  I suspect that there's a broken PATH variable in there (bin rather than /bin).